# Reading .txt file with linq, ToDictionary(...), choose array range

Tags: c#, linq

I save the content of my array to .txt file so inside, it looks like this:

Array=item1, item2, item3, item4,

then when my program restarts, it reads the content of the .txt file(the file has multiple lines), go to the line "Array=item1, item2, item3, item4," read it, and assign via loop to my array inside the program. The reason why I'm saving these items is that they can be dynamic(change name) so I don't want to hardcode it.
I'm using LINQ to read .txt file:

```
var test = File
.ReadAllLines(pathToFile).Select(x => x.Split('=', ',')).Where(x => x.Length > 4 ).ToDictionary(x=>x[0], x=>x[1]);
```

However, there is a problem, .ToDictionary can only read one value from the line. With elementSelector I can only pick one item, e.g. x=>x[1] or x=>x[2]. I would like to read all these 4 items at the same time. Some kind of range? I tried to google it but I couldn't find any solutions to my problem.

I'm using .ToDictionary because later I can do something like this:

```
if (test["Array"].Length > 0)
   for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++)
   {
      MyArray[i] = test["File Name Array"];
   }
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `ToDictionary()`? Are you trying to store each consecutive pair of items in the list as a key/value pair?

Comment: With ToDictionary(), I'm trying to get all items (currently I can only get one) and pass it to var test. Then I can read and assign it with a for loop.

Comment: You don't need `ToDictionary` to do that. Your `Where` will return an `IEnumerable<string>`, which you can enumerate directly with a `for` or `foreach`.

Comment: If I remove .ToDictionary code, how can I read it later on with If statement and for loop? My second code in the first post.

Comment: `foreach(var item in test)`. You don't need an `if` to check the length.

Comment: The thing is that my .txt file has multiple lines, so it will assign like 20 lines to the array. I need to find a way to only read this particular line and the items in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192586/discussion-between-nlawalker-and-goodnickname).

Comment: Do you have multiple lines that begin with "Array"? Using the `Split().Length` to find the right line seems like a bad idea. There is no point to using a `Dictionary` when you want an array, just use `ToArray`.